# Execute command on a pair of files

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

**Context :**I've scanned a lot of old pictures, that have writing on the back.

Using imagemagick, I can append the front and back of the picture like this :

```
montage out20.jpg out21.jpg -gravity center -geometry +1+1 -tile 1x2 out2021.jpg; rm out20.jpg out21.jpg;
#(vertical append)
```

My problem is that I have a lot of pictures to apply the command on.

Is there a way to ask bash to apply "montage" to each odd file, adding automaticly the filename that comes after it ? The output filename is also a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.jpg | while read file
do
  number=`echo $file | tr -dc 0-9`;
  if [ $((number % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    nextnumber=`echo $number + 1 | bc`;
    nextfile=`echo $file | sed s/$number/$nextnumber/`;
    outfile=`echo $file | sed s/$number/$number$nextnumber/`;
    montage $file $nextfile -gravity center -geometry +1+1 -tile 1x2 $outfile
  fi
done
```

You said to apply the montage to the odd files but provided even in your example.  The code above will work for even.  If you need the odd files to be first just change this line:

```
if [ $((number % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
```

to be this:

```
if [ $((number % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Impressive and fast ! I'll try that

Comment: I don't know if every "left" image will be even or odd, all I'm sure of is that they follow each other... So, I could have out4.jpg out5.jpg out23.jpg out 24.jpg.

Comment: If that's the case then you can probably just remove the lines that start with "if" and "fi".

Comment: Works great ! Thank very much.
Now I have to tweak it, so that it'll take a file, append it to file+1, and then jump to file+2 ....

Comment: I did it with a counter; I test if it is even. Thanks again, you rock at bash :)

Comment: I used "ls -v", for natural sort

Comment: You can do something like `nextfile=${file/$number/$nextnumber}` instead of `sed` and you don't need `bc` for integer addition - just do `((nextnumber = number + 1))`.